# pgfpathcurvebetweentime acts weird for some values

Tags: tikz-pgf

PGF chokes when generating certain Bézier subpaths.

```
\input tikz
\tikzpicture [x=1pt,y=1pt]

  \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid [step=10] (100,170);

  \foreach [count=\n] \s/\t
      in { 0/1, 0/.999, .001/1.0, 0/1.0, 
           0.25/0.50, 0.26/0.5, 0.25/.5, 0.25/0.5 }{
    \pgftext [at=\pgfpoint{50}{20*(\n)}] {\s/\t}
    \pgfpathcurvebetweentime {\s} {\t}
      { \pgfpoint   {0} {20*(\n-1)} }
      { \pgfpoint  {30} {20*(\n  )} }
      { \pgfpoint  {70} {20*(\n  )} }
      { \pgfpoint {100} {20*(\n-1)} }
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  }

\endtikzpicture
\bye
```

The MWE shows it depends from both the values and their formatting:

[image: SHAZAM]

Applying a slight perturbation to the numbers fixes the issue, but that's an unacceptable solution.

These are the only critical values I've found but there may be more.
Hopefully I'm missing something obvious. Am I? Or is this a bug?

Comment: It's TeX precision make all 1.0s --> 1.000000 and 0.5---> 0.50000 then it's OK.

Comment: @percusse True. Thanks. I still can't imagine why there should be a rounding problem using *exactly* the pair 0.25/0.5. However! The problematic numbers of my use case actually come from PGF parsed math. The keys to configure trailing zeroes seem to work but just for "formatting" commands. It seems a bit silly to use those, but they'll probably do the job. Do you know of a way to configure the math parser directly? (BTW, if it's less than trivial I'll just ask another question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm inclined to say this is a bug. The original code in `pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex` contains some optimizations which I probably thought were clever at the time, but some years on seem a bit clumsy and difficult to debug.

Ignoring the original code and re-implenting from scratch yields something which seems to work better (although not fully tested)

```
\input tikz
\catcode`\@=11

\def\pgf@@pathcurvebetweentime#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1}%
  \let\pgf@time@s=\pgfmathresult%
  \pgfmathparse{#2}%
  \let\pgf@time@t=\pgfmathresult%
  \ifdim\pgf@time@s pt>\pgf@time@t pt\relax%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pgf@time@s{1-#1}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pgf@time@t{1-#2}%
    \pgf@@@pathcurvebetweentime{#6}{#5}{#4}{#3}%
  \else%
    \pgf@@@pathcurvebetweentime{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
  \fi%
}
\def\pgf@@@pathcurvebetweentime#1#2#3#4{%
\begingroup%
  % Get the curve Q from curve P for time 0 to t
  \pgfextract@process\Pa{#1}%
  \pgfextract@process\Pb{#2}%
  \pgfextract@process\Pc{#3}%
  \pgfextract@process\Pd{#4}%
  % Qa = Pa
  \pgfextract@process\Qa{\Pa}%
  % Qb = Pa + t*(Pb-Pa).
  \pgfextract@process\Qb{%
    \pgfpointadd{\Pa}{\pgfpointscale{\pgf@time@t}{\pgfpointdiff{\Pa}{\Pb}}}%
  }%
  % Qc = Qb + t*((Pb + t*(Pc-Pb)) - Qb)
  \pgfextract@process\Qc{%
    \pgfpointadd{\Qb}{\pgfpointscale{\pgf@time@t}{\pgfpointdiff{\Qb}{\pgfpointadd{\Pb}{\pgfpointscale{\pgf@time@t}{\pgfpointdiff{\Pb}{\Pc}}}}}}%
  }%
  % Qd = (1-t)^3*Pa + 3*t(1-t)^2*Pb + 3*t^2(1-t)*Pc + t^3*Pd.
  \pgfextract@process\Qd{\pgfpointcurveattime{\pgf@time@t}{\Pa}{\Pb}{\Pc}{\Pd}}% 
  %
  % Now get the curve R from the reversed curve Q for time 0 to 1-s/t
  \pgfmathdivide@{\pgf@time@s}{\pgf@time@t}%
  \pgfmathadd@{-\pgfmathresult}{1.0}%
  \let\pgf@time@s=\pgfmathresult%
  % Rd = Qd
  \pgfextract@process\Rd{\Qd}%
  % Rc = Qd + s*(Qc-Qd).
  \pgfextract@process\Rc{%
    \pgfpointadd{\Qd}{\pgfpointscale{\pgf@time@s}{\pgfpointdiff{\Qd}{\Qc}}}%
  }%
  % Rb = Rc + s*((Qc + s*(Qb-Qc)) - Rc)
  \pgfextract@process\Rb{%
    \pgfpointadd{\Rc}{\pgfpointscale{\pgf@time@s}{\pgfpointdiff{\Rc}{\pgfpointadd{\Qc}{\pgfpointscale{\pgf@time@s}{\pgfpointdiff{\Qc}{\Qb}}}}}}%
  }%
  % Ra = (1-s)^3*Qd + 3*s(1-s)^2*Qc + 3*s^2(1-s)*Qb + s^3*Qa.
  \pgfextract@process\Ra{\pgfpointcurveattime{\pgf@time@s}{\Qd}{\Qc}{\Qb}{\Qa}}% 
  \ifpgf@ignoremoveto\else\pgfpathmoveto{\Ra}\fi%
  \pgfpathcurveto{\Rb}{\Rc}{\Rd}%
\endgroup%
}


\tikzpicture [x=1pt,y=1pt]

  \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid [step=10] (100,170);

  \foreach [count=\n] \s/\t
      in { 0./1., 0/.999, .001/1.0, 0/1.0, 
           0.25/0.50, 0.26/0.5, 0.25/.5, 0.25/0.5 }{
    \pgftext [at=\pgfpoint{50}{20*(\n)}] {\s/\t}
    \pgfpathcurvebetweentime {\s} {\t}
      { \pgfpoint   {0} {20*(\n-1)} }
      { \pgfpoint  {30} {20*(\n  )} }
      { \pgfpoint  {70} {20*(\n  )} }
      { \pgfpoint {100} {20*(\n-1)} }
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{black}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  }

\endtikzpicture
\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on the suggestion by @percusse, a quick fix that does not require direct control on the input would be

```
\input tikz

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/precision=6} % <------------------------------------

\tikzpicture [x=1pt,y=1pt]

  \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid [step=10] (100,170);

  \foreach [count=\n] \s/\t
      in { 0/1, 0/.999, .001/1.0, 0/1.0, 
           0.25/0.50, 0.26/0.5, 0.25/.5, 0.25/0.5 }{
    \pgftext [at=\pgfpoint{50}{20*(\n)}] {\s/\t}

\pgfmathroundtozerofill{\s}\let\S\pgfmathresult % <-----------------------------
\pgfmathroundtozerofill{\t}\let\T\pgfmathresult % <-----------------------------

    \pgfpathcurvebetweentime {\S} {\T}
      { \pgfpoint   {0} {20*(\n-1)} }
      { \pgfpoint  {30} {20*(\n  )} }
      { \pgfpoint  {70} {20*(\n  )} }
      { \pgfpoint {100} {20*(\n-1)} }
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  }

\endtikzpicture

\bye
```

and it produces

[image: VOILÀ]

This is not particularly elegant, but it works.

Anoher solution that *just works* is

```
\input tikz

\input fp % <-------------------------------------------------------------------
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic} % <---------------------------------------
\tikzset{/pgf/fixed point arithmetic} % <---------------------------------------

\tikzpicture [x=1pt,y=1pt]

  \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid [step=10] (100,170);

  \foreach [count=\n] \s/\t
      in { 0/1, 0/.999, .001/1.0, 0/1.0, 
           0.25/0.50, 0.26/0.5, 0.25/.5, 0.25/0.5 }{
    \pgftext [at=\pgfpoint{50}{20*(\n)}] {\s/\t}

    \pgfpathcurvebetweentime {\s} {\t}
      { \pgfpoint   {0} {20*(\n-1)} }
      { \pgfpoint  {30} {20*(\n  )} }
      { \pgfpoint  {70} {20*(\n  )} }
      { \pgfpoint {100} {20*(\n-1)} }
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  }

\endtikzpicture

\bye
```

Using FPU should work equally well, but something, somewhere, chokes on the `bad formatted float '0.0'`.